# SignalR generate multiple executions

Tags: signalr

I'm building a search engine using SignalR to deliver partial responses in real time to the client.

The problem occurs when the first search is not over, and the client modifies the value of the textbox (txtTab) and click the button (btnSearch) again. The results of the two queries are mixed because the server keeps the two concurrent executions.

I need that when the client clicks the search button the previous execution is canceled.

Tried using hub.stop () and hub.disconnect (), but I can not.

Sorry my bad english :)

```
        var busca = $.connection.hubBusca;

        busca.client.atualizaResultados = function (arr) {
            oTable.fnAddData(arr);
        };

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#btnSearch').click(function () {
                if ($('#txtTab').val() != '') {
                    busca.server.iniciar($('#txtTab').val());
                }                    
            });
        });
```

Thanks!
Luiz Fernando

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating an additional server and client method to handle the final search (which happens when #btnSearch is clicked).

Instead of invoking `busca.server.iniciar` invoke something like `busca.server.terminar`.

I would also suggest setting some sort of boolean flag before calling `busca.server.terminar` to disable `busca.client.atualizaResultados` so no preliminary search results interfere with the final search results.

Then in `HubBusca.Terminar` you could call `Clients.Caller.finalesResultados` which would not be disabled unlike `Clients.Caller.atualizaResultados`.

In this way you can ensure that your final search results which are sent to the `finalesResultados` method will not be replaced by results sent to the `atualizaResultados` client method.

Sorry for my bad Spanish method names. I used Google Translate.

Comment: Ok, but my search takes approximately 5 minutes to complete. I would like to stop the execution of the first search. I thought I'd close the connection and open a new one, but do not know how to do.

Comment: You will need to provide your own way to interrupt your long-running search. Even if the client disconnects, SignalR will not stop a hub method mid-execution. You have to do that yourself.